# Can pilots hear a car horn while on the ground?

Tags: ground-operations

In [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33610/679) I asked about the pilot's ability to give a signal to others nearby while on the ground. My question here is, if someone else wants to get the *pilot's* attention on the ground, could the pilot hear someone honking a car horn from the cockpit?

Edit: thanks for all comments. I want to ask about a situation involved large aircraft, engine running, car is near the aircraft. Such as in large airport operation. My question comes from series Ultimate Airport: Dubai when a trainee is driven to different areas of airport as part of his certification. I wonder if he can call attention of pilot in cockpit by honking the horn. I am aware that more standard mode of communication such as radio, flare or ground marshall is preferable.

Comment: What kind of aircraft and where is it that it needs to hear it? Are the engines running? Where is the car in relation to the aircraft?

Comment: Large aircraft, engine running, car is near the aircraft. Such as in large airport operation.

Comment: I think that's a firm maybe.

Comment: Pilots and airport vehicles will probably communicate by radio using the ground frequency. Remember that vehicles are moving under the control of the ground control/tower in large airports.

Comment: To continue @RonBeyer's comments:  is the engine electric?  And what kind of horn?  A regular horn is harder to hear than when someone puts a "train horn" on there car.  There are... a lot of variables not being accounted for here.

Comment: Flares can be used to contact a pilot in an emergency, ie a red flare to imply take off forbidden.

Comment: Maybe a glider or a hang glider?

Answer (score 6):

Airplane engines are loud, so if they are running I would say no, a pilot is not going to hear a car horn. If you want to get a pilot's attention without a radio you'd use light or hand signals.

Answer (score 1):

A loud air horn might just be audible through all the noise even when taxiing. This thought occurred to me when I thought about how ships use(d) quite similar steam whistles in poor visibility. The sound from waves & ship's engines and the noise reduction from the hull make the sound environment quite similar to a grounded airliner.

Of course in takeoff and landing almost everything is blocked by noise from the engine, tyres etc.